# Bash - Substitute on a variable

Tags: bash, sed

Thank you very much in advance for helping!

I'd like to transform this variable:

win_path=**/cygdrive/g**/virtual_tours/.archives/vt_template_8_0_15/test_directory_2/panos

into:

win_path_dir=**G:**/virtual_tours/.archives/vt_template_8_0_15/test_directory_2/panos

This in what I have so far, but it doesn't work.
When I echo $win_path it returns nothing (black, empty space)

```
$win_path=$(echo $i | sed -e 's/\/cygdrive\/g/G\:/g')
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good, there is only a little typo:

```
win_path=$(echo $i | sed -e 's/\/cygdrive\/g/G\:/g')
```

Do not write `$win_path` (no $) when defining the value of variable win_path.
When you write `$win_path` the shell expands the value of the variable.

Comment: Do'oh! That was a truly beginners mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't precede the variable with `$` when you're defining or setting a variable:

```
win_path=$(echo $i | sed -e 's/\/cygdrive\/g/G\:/g')
```

`$` causes the string `$name` to be replaced with the value of variable *name*, see [bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Answer (score 0):

If wine is available, [winepath](http://wiki.winehq.org/winepath) is the tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash` substitution:

```
prefix=/cygdrive/g
win_path=${winpath/#$prefix/G:}
```

Note that defining `prefix` isn't strictly necessary; it just
relieves you of the need to escape the directory separators. The
following works just fine, although it is slightly less readable:

```
win_path=${winpath/#\/cygdrive\/g/G:}
```

Comment: It's not strictly necessary; it anchors the pattern to the beginning of the string, so that you don't, e.g., change '/foo/cygdrive/g/other' to '/foo/G:/other'. You could leave it off, and in this instance it would still work.